# PHP Unable to Resolve Hosts

Tags: php, curl, dns

First discovered when PHP cURL failed to resolve hostnames. `fopen('google.com', 'r')` also fails with same error.

I checked my php.ini settings and `allow_url_fopen = On`

I'm running a custom compiled PHP-FPM with Nginx.
Here is my configure command:
`./configure --disable-rpath --disable-cli --disable-cgi --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=php --with-fpm-group=php --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-bcmath --enable-zip --enable-sockets --enable-pdo --enable-opcache --enable-ftp --with-regex --with-mhash --with-curl --with-zlib --with-pcre-regex --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-gd --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd`

I can run any commands requiring resolving dns resolution (`wget`, `ping`, etc.) work fine on the command line and resolv.conf is fine. I'm running Cent OS 6.5

Is there anything I missed to get PHP to start resolving hostnames?

Comment: fopen('google.com', 'r') should be looking for a local file called google.com, which would understandably fail.  What exactly are the parameters you are passing to fopen that is causing it to fail?

Comment: It actually tries http://google.com/

Comment: I really don't think it does try google.com.  I think if you want it to try google.com, you have to do this: fopen('http://google.com', 'r');  Otherwise, how would you ever open a file on your own drive called google.com?

And of course it turned it into a link.  Try: (fopen('http://' . 'google.com', 'r');

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out to be a chroot config in the PHP. Can't do chroot without all the appropriate libraries in the chroot.

Comment: Thank you! I removed `chroot = /var/www` and resolving started to work